# Forward request to specific site between squid proxys

Tags: redirect, proxy, navigation, squid, sites

I have two proxys (With SQUID), each one with different ISP's, Say

Proxy 1: IP 1.1.1.1, port 8080, with ISP A.

Proxy 2: IP 2.2.2.2, port 1080, with ISP B

I'm having problems with the navigation in certain sites with ISP B (Proxy 2), so I want to redirect only the requests that match those sites to the Proxy 1.

It's that possible? I have maybe a clue with cache_peer, but i dont know if its possible.

Can you guide me a little? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is completely possible. You need an acl matching those domains, a cache_peer pointing to the sibling and a cache_peer_access that match you acl with cache_peer.

Or you could do a cache_peer with a cache_peer_domain. You choose

That's all.

Comment: Thank you very much AGL. I'll try it as soon as I can.